# language redirect from GET parameter htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have this code, it redirecs www.example.com?index.php?q=home&lang=en into www.example.com/home. I would like to redirect it into www.example.com/en/home. Is it possible?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1&lang=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)(.*)$ $1[L,QSA]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$2&lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hello, thanks but I had to change code into this:  RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$2&lang=$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: and one more mistake change % with & in url :)

Comment: I got one more question, can you help me again? Is it possible to add file exception which doesn't have to be redirected?

Comment: @dontHaveName Add a `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/path/to/file.txt` above the rule